# jQuery: Chain actions on same object

Tags: jquery, chaining, jquery-easyui

I know there are various questions on jQuery chaining already, but I couldn't find an answer to this (probably rather simple) one. Forgive a newcomer to jQuery.

What I am looking for is a short way to apply different actions/events to the same object. More specific, I have the following code

```
$('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Title').dialog('refresh','dlg.html');
```

Is there a way not to write `.dialog` three times, but rather something along the lines of

```
$('#dlg').dialog(action 1, action 2, etc.)
```

? I am not familiar with the syntax yet, so I have no clue whether the arguments need to go in curly braces, with semicolons in between, or commas, or... Thanks for any help!

P.S.: The dialog in this example is a jQuery EasyUI dialog, if that makes any difference.

---

**Update:** Seeing that the answer to my question appears to be "no", what would be the *best* way to write the command above? I.e. is

```
$('#dlg').dialog('open')
$('#dlg').dialog('setTitle','Title')
$('#dlg').dialog('refresh','dlg.html')
```

better/worse in terms of efficiency compared to the line above, or is there yet another (better) way? Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you're doing, there is basically no alternative. You could do something mad with a loop, but at the end of the day it's just adding complexity and unless you are doing this hundreds of times throughout your code, it's not worth the effort.

I assume you're aware you can pass an object containing various values in one call to init a dialog, as per the EasyUI docs:

```
$('#dd').dialog({  
    title: 'My Dialog',  
    width: 400,  
    height: 200,  
    closed: false,  
    cache: false,  
    href: 'get_content.php',  
    modal: true  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but does this create a new dialog or modify an existing with the id? (sorry if this is a stupid question) Also, this wouldn't allow me to refresh in the same query, I guess? Maybe you also have an answer to the updated question with regards to efficiency?

Comment: This will work only once, when the `dialog` is created, after that if you want to modify it won't work

Answer (score 1):

No. in jQuery there is no way to achieve this, but you can check the specific implementations for any support.

Another solution to test will to `destroy` and create the dialog every time.

```
$('#dlg').dialog('destroy');
$('#dlg').dialog({....})
```

Comment: Thanks! Given the impossibility, what would be the most efficient way for the code example above (see my update)?

Comment: Chaining will be the efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able so set some of the widget parameters all at once but then you still have to call method like 'open' afterwards

```
$('#target').dialog(
    width: 400,  
    height: 200,
    title:,
    // ...
}); 
$('#target').open()
// ...
```

see [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) for infos about dialog's parameters  and widget signatures